# Element faces-config must be declared

Tags: intellij-idea, jsf, faces-config

I've got this error in project *faces-config.xml* file in my *IntelliJ* IDE:

> Element faces-config must be declared

Here is my faces-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd"
        version="2.3">
    
</faces-config>
```

And pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    ...

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
>     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd"
> ```

Try opening http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd in your favorite webbrowser. It returns 404. In other words, this URL is not correct. The IDE's built-in XML parser is also struggling this way. It cannot find the declaration of `<faces-config>` root element there.

It's not clear which JSF version exactly you intend to develop with. If it's 2.3, as indicated by `version="2.3"`, then you should be using http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd instead, as specified in "Java EE 8 Schema Resources" section of the webpage behind http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee.

```xml
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3">
```

But if it's indeed 3.0, the first Jakartified version (i.e. you should be using `jakarta.*` package for Jakarta EE API over all place instead of `javax.*` package), then you should be using the following deployment descriptor root declaration as specified in "Jakarta EE 9" section of the webpage behind https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee.

```xml
<faces-config
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
        https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

#### See also:

- [Jakarta Faces 4.0 specification - 11.3.5 Application Configuration Resource Format](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/jakarta-faces-4.0.html#a6254)

Comment: Oh, Tnx. My problem was solved with your solution. I used [this](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/jakarta-faces-3.0.html#a6254) official source for faces-config tag! [link](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/jakarta-faces-3.0.html#a6254)

Comment: Ah, that's a bug in the 3.0 spec! Must have slipped through during the relatively chaotic migration from Oracle to Eclipse. It's already fixed in 4.0 spec: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/jakarta-faces-4.0.html#a6254

Comment: You specified a link at the end of your answer, but it returns 404 as well https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_4_0.xsd and I've got same error in question when changes to version 4.0

Comment: The Faces 4.0 release is currently indeed still in progress at the jakarta.ee side. The PR for schemas is currently still open: https://github.com/jakartaee/jakarta.ee/pull/1472